# What does "Not where the black coach of sorrow has taken you" mean?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

I heard this in "Gloomy Sunday" song. Is it true that it means: "the death coach carried you to unknown place..."?
Thanks.

Comment: It's probably "know", not "no".

Comment: I don't know! you can find this lyric in google.

Comment: Questions about the meaning of song lyrics are [generally off-topic here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/995/are-interpretations-of-song-lyrics-poems-or-other-creative-works-on-topic/997#997).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the lyric you're writing about:

```
Not where the black coach 
Of sorrow has taken you.
```

The general meaning is that the "black coach of sorrow" is a metaphor for death, and the implied place it has taken the person being sung about is the afterlife.

This lyric poetically expresses the metaphor that death is like a journey to a place from which a person cannot return.

Comment: To put it in easier words: “Little white flowers will never awaken you / Not where the black coach of sorrow has taken you” could be paraphrased/explained as, “The little white flowers people put on your coffin/grave will never bring you back to life—not from the place where death has brought you”.